# Dataframe in R, different numbers of rows and columns

Tags: r

I am working with a document in excel, which I import in R as a list. This list consists of multiple dataframe types. For instance, when I type

```
data_list <- import_list("my_doc.xlsx")
```

I obtain a list with 3 types of dataframes- either 1* 30, 30* 31 or 0* 1. As one can imagine, the 0*1 are scalar values.

After this, I make a consolidated dataframe as follows:

```
my_data<- ldply (data_list, data.frame)
my_data<-t(my_data)
colnames(my_data) <- my_data[1,]
my_data<- my_data[-1,]
my_data1<-matrix(as.numeric(unlist(my_data)),nrow=nrow(my_data))
my_data1<-data.frame(my_data1)
```

I now obtain a single dataframe, entitled my_data1, with variables appropriately named. However, I lose all scalar variables. Intuitively, one way to go about it, would be to identify all the scalars, and make a vector of them which repeats in value, and is of the same length (i.e. 30), as the other variables. At the moment, they simply disappear.

Any help is much appreciated!

An example of the datastructure is as follows. a is the scalar, and b represents an example of the 1*30 variable. The ... represent the continuation from period 2 to 30.

```
a= structure(list(`24` = logical(0)), row.names = character(0), class = "data.frame"))
     
b= structure(list(period1 = 1, period2 = 2, 
   period3 = 3, period4 = 4, 
   period5 = 5), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"),
```

One issue here is that  a is stored as logical(0). How can I change this?

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying to stack these datasets? Are you trying to append columns into one dataframe? Could you please post some sample data so we have something to work with?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I wish to append them in one dataframe, with the variables alongside each other.

Comment: Can you post some data for each list element using `dput` so we can better understand the structure? It is helpful if you post a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Do you need `library(dplyr); bind_cols(data_list)`

Comment: I tried to bind_cols(data_list), but was returned an error : Can't recycle `..13` (size 30) to match `..36` (size 0).

Comment: How do you intend of `a` and `b` to fit together? Do you want to add `b` as a column to `a` so that you then have a 1x4 dataframe?

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a small reproducible example with expecetd output

Comment: @LMc a and b can be fit together by making a a 30*1 vector, say, by repeating the scalar value for the length of b

Comment: Please show your data as it currently is and what you expect your output to look like so we can help. Based on what you've posted you could do `rbind(b, rep(names(a), ncol(b)))`. According to what you've posted this should give you a 2x30 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dplyr::bind_rows` which keep the column from 0 * 1 dataframe and add it in the final dataframe with `NA`s.

```
result <- dplyr::bind_rows(a, b)
result

#  24 period1 period2 ...period30
#1 NA       5       4           4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I wanted to do a column bind, and put them alongside each other. One problem is that although a and b are dataframes, a has type double, but b has type logical[[0]. I'm trying to change that at the moment...

Comment: Although I am using `bind_rows` it is column binding the data if you see the output it has got a column called `24` in it. If this is not what you want can you update your post to show expected output for the data shared? Also it would be good if you remove all the `>` in `dput` data. It makes it really difficult to copy and we have to manually remove it to copy the data.

Comment: Thanks. One of the main issues, it seems to me, is that a is stored as logical. Although a is a dataframe, from the ldply command, R does  not recognize a as a numeric/integer variable of length 1. It is an atomic vector. When I try to store it as double, say, using: b$mydata1<-as.double(b$mydata1), I get an NA. This should be stored as a numeric/float variable named b, of value 24

Comment: Can you edit your post to include `dput(data_list)` before running the `ldply` command?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I just did -as you can see, a is stored just as a logical. B is stored as a double with 5 values, corresponding to different periods. The problem is this- how can I change a to be the exact same structure as b? Basically, for a, have the structure as period1=24, period2=24, period3=24, period4=25 and period5=24?

Comment: Maybe : `bind_rows(bind_rows(a, b), b)`

Comment: I get the error: Error: Internal error in `vec_assign()`: `value` should have been recycled to fit `x`.

Comment: Hi @Ronak - one issue here is that a is stored as logical(0). How can I change this?

Comment: There is no data in `a` so you cannot change it. `a` has 0 rows.